# Looping through an array, creating DOM-Elements with different contents

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, for-loop

i am building a Angular 6 Project and i'm stuck, here's the situation:

I have an Array called "`technologies`":

```
["HTML", "CSS", "Angular"]
```

I have a locally stored JSON called "`technologiesSource`":

```
{
    "HTML": {
        "name": "HTML",
        "image": "html.png",
        "link": "https://blabla.de/"
    },
    [ ... ]
}
```

I am trying to achieve that Angular creates a DOM element for every item in the `technologies` - Array.
Inside that DOM - Element, it should print out some info according to the details inside the `technologiesSource` - JSON and add it as a child to a certain DIV-Element.

I'm gonna try to describe it the best way i can:

```
for (i = 0; i < technologies.length; i++){

    GIVE Document.getElementById('techRow') THIS CHILD ELEMENT: {

        <div>
            // expected result: technologiesSource.HTML.image
            <img src="{technologiesSource[technologies[i]].image}" />

            // expected result: technologiesSource.HTML.name
            <h3>{technologiesSource[technologies[i]].name}</h3>
        </div>
    }

}
```

I feel like i am kinda close, but i am stuck at this point and can't proceed.

Can anyone help me figuring out what's the correct procedure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `*ngFor` in your component template like this:

```
<div id="techRow">
  <div *ngFor="let tech of technologies">
    <img [src]="technologiesSource[tech].image">
    <h3>{{technologiesSource[tech].name}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is very basic Angular stuff, and I would advise you to follow the tutorials and guides available [here](https://angular.io/docs)

Comment: The sad thing is, i already did that tutorial... thank you for your help Pierre, i'm going to try it and comment again with the results

Comment: you were right, i shouldn't have tried it from the JS side, after some attempts i have everything in order now! thank you very much

Comment: @SHRX good to hear! Angular can have a steep learning curve, but once you are over the first bumps it does make your life a lot easier :) Thereby, you should not use JS to insert a html string. All the angular stuff do not work anymore, like string interpolation and property binding

Comment: Well, that's a problem i didn't even think about :) the only argument i needed to know was my monstrosity of JS code compared to your Angular-4-Liner :) thanks again, you made my day! For me, this is a big one, since thats the first time i am creating subpages dynamically from a JSON